# Ahoy, Ye Traveler!

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry

> I am a traveler.
>
> In birth, I had struggles, but shifted a tad to become a double saint,
>
> Based, to be honest, on what I could do with a bit of paint.
>
> I'm proud to say that I became unbeatable there,
>
> although I had to drop one loss because of some wear.
>
> My next stop was spectacular - cloud nine!
>
> In my 7 there I had 2 - quite fine!
>
> I was missing something there, though,
>
> So I moved on to a place where I'd get in the flow.
>
> The thing I was missing, I got not once, but twice!
>
> It felt good, though it came with a price.
>
> I returned to the place that was missing one thing
>
> And brought it back with me, now the king.
>
> I told you, I'm a traveler.
>
> There's one more major stop in my long journey
>
> to a lake in the midst of the angels.
>
> That's where I am now, but that's not where I'll stay.
>
> I am a traveler, and I'll always be that way.
>
> What is my name?

---

The accepted answer should include accurate explanations for each line in addition to the final answer, including the title, which contains two indirect hints.

***Note:*** (that kind of provides a hint)

> In this poem, the term "traveler" can be taken in alternative sense to the one intended. Applying "traveler" in that way to the subject of the riddle is vaguely humorous, but not really correct, and I'm not trying to say anything in that direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you

> LeBron James?

I am a traveler.

> A basketball player (who gets away with Eurosteps and travels more than he’d admit).

In birth, I had struggles, but shifted a tad to become a double saint,

> He grew up in a rough neighbourhood in Akron while his Mom tried to earn a living. Things started to get better when he entered high school -- he played for St. Vincent-St. Mary High School (hence double saint).

Based, to be honest, on what I could do with a bit of paint.

> He plays Power Forward, which is a position “in the paint” in basketball (let’s be honest, he plays every position)

I'm proud to say that I became unbeatable there,

> The St. Vincent-St. Mary Fighting Irish were almost unbeatable -- they went 27-0, 26-1, 23-4, and 26-1 during LeBron's four years in high school, winning the state championships 3 times.

although I had to drop one loss because of some wear.

> I had initially thought this referred to his state championship loss in his junior year, but I believe the better fit is that SV-SM had to forfeit a game because he accepted two throwback jerseys as compensation for posing for pictures, a violation of high school sports rules in Ohio.

My next stop was spectacular - cloud nine!

> He played in the NBA, starting with his hometown Cleveland Cavaliers.

In my 7 there I had 2 - quite fine!

> He won two league MVP awards in his 7 years in Cleveland.

I was missing something there, though,

> He never won a ring during his first stint in Cleveland.

So I moved on to a place where I'd get in the flow.

> The LeDecision took him to South Beach and the Miami Heat.

The thing I was missing, I got not once, but twice!

> He won two championships (but promised Miami like 7 though).

It felt good, though it came with a price.

> Winning is good, the price was the hatred of Northeastern Ohio basketball fans, and also Chris Bosh’s career.

I returned to the place that was missing one thing

> He returned to Cleveland, missing a championship.

And brought it back with me, now the king.

> Never forget the Warriors blew a 3-1 lead (to LeBron).

I told you, I'm a traveler.

> (And gets all of the calls).

There's one more major stop in my long journey

> He moved on again...

to a lake in the midst of the angels.

> To Los Angeles, to play for the Lakers (who are TERRIBLE this year).

That's where I am now, but that's not where I'll stay.

> He’s going to play with Bronny when his son gets to the NBA.

I am a traveler, and I'll always be that way.

> (Please come to Toronto, Kyle Lowry still has nightmares about last postseason).

What is my name?

> LeBron James!

Comment: Definitely on the right track here, but some of the line-by-line explanations could be improved on. Up to LeDecison is a little iffy-you've missed a stop in his travels (an early one), and it results in some stretches for a few explanations.

Comment: True, fair enough -- I forgot about some of that! Thanks @Brandon_J -- will update now!

Comment: @Brandon_J how does this look now?

Comment: Very nice! You got it!

Comment: Great puzzle, @Brandon_J! Don't often see a lot of sports puzzles on here, so this was a fun change of pace!! :D

Answer (score 5):

I can't answer the question because I don't know enough about

> basketball.

Travelling

> is a bad thing in that game.

The one part of the clue I can parse is that

> a lake in the midst of the angels

appears to refer to

> the Los Angeles Lakers.

Comment: You are on the right track for that clue. Nice job spotting that!